# update 'cell' in csv row by finding a unique value in a column header?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a simple csv like this:

```
name,age,color,team,completed
tim,34,green,5
jim,31,blue,6
kim,33,yellow,5
```

I want to in python (pandas is fine if need be an third party module) find an id, so in this case name (row), and then update the value under 'completed' with a YES. The names will always be unique. The sheet may not always be in the same order, but the header names will always be the same.

Is there a way to find the cell coords at name=="Jim" and 'completed' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good evening,

#### Importing CSV

While I understand you may desire only using core Python modules, I recommend using Pandas for this task.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv')
```

#### Conditional Variable Assignment

One way is to use `.loc[row, column]` to return rows where `df['name'] == 'jim'` and assign a new column "completed" to "YES". The rows where the column `name` is not equal to "jim" will be set to missing values.

```py
df.loc[df['name'] == 'jim', 'completed'] = 'YES'
```